# Optimize self-join Oracle SQL query with LAG/LEAD analytic functions?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, sqlperformance

We have an Oracle SQL query to identify records where the value of a table column has changed from one record to another. Relevant columns are (ID, SOME_COLUMN, FROM_DATE, TO_DATE) where the ID is not unique, and FROM_DATE and TO_DATE determine the time interval for which the the particular row for that ID was effective, i.e.

```
(ID1, VAL1, 01/01/2016, 03/01/2016)
(ID1, VAL2, 04/01/2016, 09/01/2016)
(ID1, VAL3, 10/01/2016, 19/01/2016)
```

etc.

We could implement this using the following self-join

```
SELECT N.ID
       O.SOME_COLUMN OLD_VALUE,
       N.SOME_COLUMN NEW_VALUE
FROM OUR_TABLE N, OUR_TABLE O
WHERE N.ID = O.ID
  AND N.FROM_DATE - 1 = O.TO_DATE
  AND N.SOME_COLUMN <> O.SOME_COLUMN
```

however since the table contains 100 millions of records, it quite hits the performance. Is there a more effective way to do this? Someone hinted analytic functions (e.g. LAG), but we could not figure out a working solution so far. Any ideas would be appreciated

Comment: Your question is not clear.  Your dates do not overlap at all, and it is unclear what results you want.

Comment: Dates are indeed not overlapping, they represent time intervals, during which the particular table row belonging to that ID was effective. As you see in the example, the FROM_DATE of an interval is always +1 added to the TO_DATE of the previous interval. We need results, where the value of SOME_COLUMN has changed from one interval to another. Actually checking your below answer you seem to have interpreted everything correctly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can use `LEAD()` to fetch the last value :

```
SELECT t.id,
       t.some_column as OLD_VALUE,
       LEAD(t.some_column) OVER(PARTITION BY t.id ORDER BY t.from_date) as NEW_VALUE
FROM YourTable t
```

If you want only changes, wrap it with another select and filter `OLD_VALUE <> NEW_VALUE`

Answer (score 2):

If you want the old value and the new value in a single row, then use `lag()`:

```
select t.*,
       lag(some_column) over (partition by id order by from_date) as prev_val
from t;
```

If the values may not change (as suggested by your sample query):

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lag(some_column) over (partition by id order by from_date) as prev_val
      from t
     ) t
where prev_val <> some_column;
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this is the LAG() approach you were talking about.

```
SELECT * 
  FROM (
    SELECT ID
           N.SOME_COLUMN NEW_VALUE,
           N.FROM_DATE,
           lag(N.SOME_COLUMN) over (partition by N.ID order by FROM_DATE) OLD_VALUE,
           lag(N.TO_DATE) over (partition by N.ID order by FROM_DATE) OLD_TO_DATE,
    FROM OUR_TABLE N
) T
WHERE FROM_DATE - 1 = OLD_TO_DATE
  AND NEW_VALUE<> OLD_VALUE;
```

Comment: @hammerfest . . . Actually, this was the third answer.  By your reasoning, you should accept Sagi's answer.  If you mouse over the "time" above the name (which now says "answered 2 hours ago"), you will see the exact time of the answer.

Comment: It seems you are right, I have simply mischanged the two answers after trying out the solutions and returning to the question page. I have changed the accept mark now. @vercelli: I am sorry, your answer is as correct as well but it was indeed not the first one.